# How to delete all databases on Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I take daily backs of our postgres development box using:
    pg_dumpall -h 127.0.0.1 -U user -w | gzip blah.gz

Since 9.0 is now a release candidate I would like to restore this daily backup on a daily basis to a postgres9.0rc1 box for testing, however I'm not sure how to script it repeatedly. Is there some directory I can nuke to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Granted the question is 9 years old at this point, but it's still the second google result for deleting all databases.  If you just want to go from N DBs to 0 without jacking with your config and also having rummage through the file system, this is a much better answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548640/3499424

From the answer, the following script will generate N `drop database` commands, one for each non-template DB:

```sql
select 'drop database "'||datname||'";'
from pg_database
where datistemplate=false;
```

From there, you can edit and run manually, or pipe further along into a script.  Here's a somewhat verbose one-liner:

`echo \pset pager off \copy (select 'drop database "'||datname||'";' from pg_database where datistemplate=false) to STDOUT; | psql -U <user> -d postgres | <appropriate grep> | psql -U <user> -d postgres`

Explanation:

1. This is a series of pipes
2. `echo \pset pager off \copy (select 'drop database "'||datname||'";' from pg_database where datistemplate=false) to STDOUT;` generates a string for psql to execute

   1. `\pset pager off` ensures you get all records instead of that (54 rows) crap
   2. `\copy (select 'drop database "'||datname||'";' from pg_database where datistemplate=false) to STDOUT;` executes the aforementioned query, sending the result to STDOUT. We have to do this since we lead with `\pset`.
3. `| psql -U <user> -d postgres` pipes said string into psql, which executes it. Replace `<user>` with the user you want to use
4. `| <appropriate grep>` is for stripping out the "Pager usage is off" line

   1. Windows users can use `findstr /v "Pager"` or `findstr /b "drop"`
   2. *nix users can use `grep 'drop'`
5. `| psql -U <user> -d postgres` pipes the resulting set of `drop database` commands into psql again, which executes them, thus dropping all the databases
6. WARNING: Without any additional filtering, this *will* also drop the `postgres` database.  You can strip it either in the `SELECT` or the grep if you don't want that to happen.

Comment: Updating the accepted answer to keep up with the times.

Comment: Cool aid here. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 22):

You can do "drop cluster" and "create cluster" which will automtically erase all databases. Erase all data in you $PGDATA directory and reinit the cluster using:

```
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Comment: To be clear, you should replace `/usr/local/pgsql/data` with whatever your `$PGDATA` directory is. For example, for PostgreSQL installed via Homebrew, it's `/usr/local/var/postgres`. Also, if you export `$PGDATA`, then you can run `initdb` with no arguments. Finally, do note that deleting your `$PGDATA` directory is a separate step. `initdb` does not do it for you. Oh, and the deletion won't work right if your `postgres` server is still running.

Answer (score 21):

You can use:

```
$ pg_dropcluster 9.2 main
$ pg_createcluster 9.2 main
$ pg_ctlcluster 9.2 main start
$ pg_restore -f your_dump_file
```

where `9.2` = `cluster version` and `main` = `cluster name`

Comment: Those are not standard Postgres tools if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: these are debian scripts.

Comment: I would recommend using the flag `-e 'UTF-8'` for `pg_createcluster` otherwise you may have to be changed later if you want UTF-8 databases and the locale is not set to UTF8.

Comment: WARNING: this also nukes your postgres config -- I literally just wanted a CLEAN database, NOT to also purge the previously optimized config... *grumble* at least it was the non-production server.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the database data somewhere else can achieve the same as deleting, and you can easily move it back in case you change your mind (But be sure to be careful and back up your data in any case).

1) Create a directory somewhere (e.g. `/home/USERNAME/BACKUPDIR`).

2) As a superuser go to the postgresql data directory (Fedora e.g. `/var/lib/pgsql/`)

3) Move the `data` to your backup folder: `mv data /home/USERNAME/BACKUPDIR`

4) Then reinit a new database using e.g. `sudo postgresql-setup --initdb --unit postgresql`

Answer (score -1):

run this command as root:

```
cd /var/lib/postgresql/ && sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT 'dropdb '||datname||'' FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false AND datallowconn = true And datname NOT IN ('postgres')" |grep ' dropdb ' |  sudo -u postgres /bin/bash ; cd
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).