# how to drop all databases except few ones in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to drop all of the databases except few ones. 
Lets say there are 20 databases and I want to delete 18 out of them but keep 2 as it is the latest ones and are in use.

Please suggest.

Comment: "drop database databasename" for your deletable 18 databases..

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!  I want a single script where I would like to mention only the 2 databases names which I want to keep.

Comment: @user3800715 ... and when you tried to write this script yourself, using the scripting language of your choice, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @CraigRinger I am not sure how to write the script for this query. Can someone provide a script for the same compatible to postgres?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

First, execute the following query in the psql terminal.

```
select 'drop database "'||datname||'";'
from pg_database
where datistemplate=false;
```

This will generate `drop database` command for all the databases. Copy the result in a text editor and exclude(delete) what you want to keep and save it as `dd.sql` file. And execute it like this:

```
psql -d postgres -f dd.sql
```

Comment: optionally: `psql -d postgres < <( psql -Atc "select 'drop database \"'||datname||'\";' from pg_database where datistemplate=false /* AND add_extra_conditions_here */;")`

Answer (score 12):

From pgAdmin you can now select properties on a database, select DBs to drop and click delete/drop. Quick and easy! Drop selected databases:
[image: Drop selected databases]

Answer (score 5):

As accepted answer kinda demonstrates it, dropping multiple databases was particularly tedious for me, so I wrote an helper script to alleviate this operation : https://github.com/Kraymer/ezdropdb

In short, you enter a pattern that the databases you want to suppress must match then all db names results are listed and there is a final prompt where you can enter which ones of those to drop (cf screenshot on project page) .